# How do I use the joins feature of the new API

Tags: api, 4.7

4.7 lists the ability to use joins for API queries, but I can't find anything in the docs or in the API Explorer.  Can someone point me to documentation or examples?

Answer (score 4):

The JIRA Issue for this feature https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17795 reads

> This adds support for joins in api.get operations to fetch information
>   from more than one table.
>
> It also adds ACL enforcement to the Contact and related (email,
>   address, phone, etc) apis for get, create & delete actions.

The JIRA issue links to a couple of pull requests; **[pull request 7565](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7565) includes a comment that has screen shots and descriptions (and one join example)**.

Comment: Admittedly not a ton to go off of, but a start.

Answer (score 1):

4.7.1 explorer includes the Join options and is reasonably intuitive.  (4.7.0 did not.)